# Use external resources within an event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

Consider the following program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var MyEventThrower = new EventThrower();
        var log= new List<string>();
        log.Add("Log Initialized");
        MyEventThrower.Event += LogEvent;
        MyEventThrower.RaiseEvent();
        foreach (var item in log)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    static void LogEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log.Add(sender.ToString()); //obviously doesn't work, 
                                    //but this is the sort of 
                                    //behavior I want to achieve.
    }
}
```

for reference:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)

public class EventThrower
{
    public event EventHandler Event;
    protected virtual void OnEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Event!= null)
        {
            Event(this, e);
        }
    }
    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        OnEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 }
```

Edit: My problem here is that log is not within the same context as the event handler.  I see now that I can fix that by making it a static class member.

Comment: What is the  expected behaviour? When I ran your program, it executed the `LogEvent` method. Obviously after correcting some typos.

Comment: You were able to run the program with the `log.Add()` method in the event handler?  `log` doesn't exist under that context.  How did you fix it?  Also, i'll correct the typos now.  I typed out this program within the SO Question box, which I shouldn't have done =P

Comment: They are **not** executed in different threads.  It is very unclear what problem you are trying to solve, as-is there isn't any other than making the "log" variable a static class member.

Comment: For some reason, In my client application, I felt that making my external resource a static class member would prevent me from doing what I wanted to do with it, but I now realize that I was very wrong.  Making it a static class member solves the problem.

Comment: another approach would be to populate the sender and event args with the objects that you need to act on

Comment: @ConradFrix but I presume that I could only do that with things that I have access to within the EventThrower class, right?

Comment: @JHixson yes and typically it does (see the inheritors of [event args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx#inheritanceContinued). In your case  you can grant that access via a RaiseEvent signature like public void `RaiseEvent(object sender, List<string> Log)`. It's hard to tell what the right thing to do in your case is since you don't really need the event at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to use a lambda to close over the list:

```
var MyEventThrower = new EventThrower();
var log= new List<string>();
log.Add("Log Initialized");

MyEventThrower.Event += (sender, args) => log.Add(sender.ToString());

MyEventThrower.RaiseEvent();
foreach (var item in log)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea that you could do that!  I knew that there had to be something like this.  However, I realized that a much simpler solution is to take the log and make it a static class member, but I will definitely use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to use your log variable/list for anything else, so I'm making the assumption you only have to facilitate logging in the way you designed your code.

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    var logger = new Logger();
    logger.Log("Log Initialized");

    var MyEventThrower = new EventThrower();
    MyEventThrower.Event += (sender, _) => logger.Log(Convert.ToString(sender));
    MyEventThrower.RaiseEvent();
}

public class Logger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

This let's you wrap the implementation detail inside of a logger class. You could even extend this further by creating your own sort of ILogger interface and making different Logger implementations (i..e one for a file, one for console etc). If you're only ever planning on writing to the console, this is potentially overkill.

The one thing I do like about using a class to wrap the actual logging is that the implementation is in **one** spot. If you ever decide you want all your log messages to have **"DEBUG: "** prepended to the message you're logging, you only need to do it in one spot.

The other thing I like about this compared to the original solution is that you're not adding things to a list and then iterating over them again to print out information. You're doing it as the event is triggered. This will save on memory usage too (i.e. not holding all of your log messages in a list before you're ready to output them). If I misunderstood why you actually have that log list of strings, then I apologize for this.

Comment: I think this is a pretty contrived example merely meant to demonstrate accessing an object from the event receiver, rather than to say that this is how he's using his logging from his program.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for clarifying.